# Angular - How to update table element via its index in a filtered table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I have a table which gets its data from a `MatTableDataSource`. The data source contains a filter which can be used to only show elements in the table which have a specific attribute set to either `true` or `false`. This is how I add the filter to the data source in my `ngOnInit()` function:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function (record, filter) {
  return record.disabled === ConverterService.toBoolean(filter);
};

this.dataSource.filter = "false";
```

Inside the table I have a button for each element which can be clicked to open an edit dialog so the user can change any of the element attributes. After closing the dialog, I use the table index to overwrite the old element with the new element that was returned by the edit dialog. This is how the function which opens the dialog and updates the table data looks like:

```
  editProjectDialog(projectId: number, index: number, $event: MouseEvent) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditProjectDialogComponent, {
      data: projectId,
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      this.projects[index] = result;
      this.dataSource.data = this.projects;
    });
  }
```

This is how the function is called:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Edit</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index">
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="editProjectDialog(element.id, index, $event)"
        matTooltip="Edit"
      >
        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

This code used to work just fine while there was no filter added to the data source, but now it no longer works because the index in the table does not match the index in the `projects` array (because the `projects` array contains all elements and the index is only for the filtered elements which are displayed in the table). I also tried to directly modify the element by replacing `this.projects[index]` with `this.dataSource.data[index]` or even with `this.dataSource.filteredData[index]` but none of this seemed to work. How can I update the edited element in the data source to apply the changes to the table?

Comment: Can you try provide a StackBlitz, would be easier to understand the problem

Comment: @vicnoob It always takes me basically forever to create a working StackBlitz for showing just about any problem so I try to avoid it if possible. The site often gets stuck loading or randomly stops responding in my browser so it is quite a pain to try getting anything done in it. Is there anything specific you don't understand about my question? The main problem is that not all of the elements are shown to the user because of the filter, so I cannot use the index of the element in the filtered table to access the element in the array anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably get the right index using another method. How about looking for the element in the `projects` array like this:

```
const rightIndex = this.projects.findIndex(item => item.id === result.id);
this.projects[rightIndex] = result;
this.dataSource.data = this.projects;
```

After you find the correct index, then you can go ahead and replace the element. You might need to destructure the projects array when assigning it as the `dataSource.data` like this: `this.dataSource.data = [...this.projects];`

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I also had this idea already but I was hoping that there is an easier solution so I do not have to manually search for the element via its ID. However, if there is none then I'll probably have to do it like you suggested.